# How to implement mutation method for flutter + ferry + hasura?

Tags: flutter, dart, hasura

I really googled many times for doing graphql mutation on flutter using ferry and hasura.
but i couldn't do it.

please somebody help me with some examples.

```
final input = GInsertLikeReqBuilder()
  ..vars.object.drama_id = GuuidBuilder()
  ..vars.object.user_id = GuuidBuilder();
  
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [           
        IconButton(               
          onPressed: () {                 
            client
              .request(GInsertLikeReq((b) => b))
              .listen(
                (event) {
                  print(event.graphqlErrors);                 
                }
              );
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.comment)),
        Text('$views reviews'),
```

Comment: now, im doing like this. ```final input = GInsertLikeReqBuilder()
      ..vars.object.drama_id = GuuidBuilder()
      ..vars.object.user_id = GuuidBuilder();
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                client.request(GInsertLikeReq((b) => b)).listen((event) {
                  print(event.graphqlErrors);
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.comment)),
          Text('$views reviews'),```

Comment: Have you read Ferry's [doc](https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/)? it comes with a demo app too.

Comment: May be little late. 
But, I found mutation is mentioned in ferry docs: https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/mutations